# .Net - Visual Studio 2010 Not Recognizing Certain HTML and CSS Elements on ASP page

Tags: asp.net, html, css, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to set up my new development environment. I am using source control, so none of the code itself has changed.

One of the issues I have run into is that VS2010 is not recognizing certain HTML & CSS elements.

```
<body MS_POSITIONING="GridLayout">
<form id="_Default" style="MARGIN: 5px" method="post" runat="server" 
                onsubmit="return document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';">
<div class="SectionTitle" style="WIDTH: 780px">Portfolio Search</div>
<table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="3" width="780" border="0">
```

In the above block, VS will not recognize:

- MS_Positioning
- Cellspacing
- Cellpadding
- Border

The code hasn't changed since it worked on my previous PC (also VS2010).

Comment: I believe those are deprecated attributes that don't comply with XHTML 1+/HTML 5+. There is a setting in the Html Source Editing toolbar that allows you to change the target markup version.

Comment: Are you sure that the new VS2010 is the same version? Have you applied all the optional updates?

Comment: @jrummell are you talking about the target validation? I have that set to HTML 4

Comment: @JamesCulshaw it is the same version, and I have the same Service pack and feature releases installed.

Comment: @MrCarder Yes, sorry. I forgot what how it was labeled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that your Visual Studio is set to recognize valid HTML 4 or HTML 5.

Also, HTML 4 requires that all attributes be in lower case. So you HTML should be:

```
<body ms_positioning="GridLayout">
...
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" width="780" border="0">
```

Comment: Ok, this helps with the cellspacing etc. but the error under MS Positioning is that it is not a valid attribute. It is not an invalid formatting error.

Comment: Why would that change though? It worked fine as HTML 4 on my previous machine

Comment: Your HTML will be fine in a browser. The problem is how Visual Studio sees it. What Visual Studio says and what a browser does are two very different things.

Comment: Somehow, turning on IIS Windows Authentication fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

When you are viewing the source view of the .aspx page there should be a dropdown menu in one of the toolbars in VS2010 that sets the 'target schema for validation'. Try changing this to 'Internet Explorer 6.0'.